# Virtualbox guest additions installation in CentOS8 gives "kernel headers not found" error

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Running `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` in CentOS8 gives following error:

```
Kernel headers not found for target kernel 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64. Please install them and execute /sbin/rcvboxadd setup
ValueError: File context for /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.0.22/other/mount.vboxsf already defined
modprobe vboxguest failed
```

How do I install the required kernel headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# dnf update -y
# dnf install kernel-devel make gcc -y
```

Followed by reboot in case a new kernel gets installed should fix it for you.

Comment: yep.  tried that too.  no love.  same error.  but i'll spin up a fresh copy and try again.

Comment: ok.  fresh copy.  worked as you promised.  thank you.  wish i knew what went sideways.  but hey it works.  moving on.  again, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

After installing all the required packages, it still did not work for me. Then I got a crucial hint as to what was wrong, some subversion of kernel-devel must have been installed for me..

Have a look at

```
ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

For me it was pointing at a non-existing directory ie. /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 while the real directory looked similar but different it was /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2.x86_64

So I copied the contents from the 193.14.2 directory to the /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 one and restarted the install script. I probably should have linked it instead op cp -R but whatever..

Comment: This was absolutely the issue I had, and this worked perfectly. Thanks for posting that!

Comment: I can't believe that my link was pointing to the wrong place.  I "fixed" it but I'm not 100% sure it is now pointing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue with Centos 8.  I found that I had to run the following to install the right packages for everything to work.

```
dnf update -y
dnf install -y kernel-devel kernel-header* make gcc elfutils-libelf-devel
```

The last package was missing from other answers and was a package suggested by the error log for virtual box (/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log).  Without the elfutils-libelf-devel the kernel modules would fail to build.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this with command as root

$ yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)

And re-run Guest Additions script

I receive an error after a fill seconds, but works fine!